# Python: How do I add a While time loop code to a EEG CSV export for better clarity

Tags: python, time, while-loop, european-data-format

I am currently having trouble with my EEG data that I have from the Siena Scalp Database from physio.
The EEG data that I have has around 30 channels and a text file that displays when a seizure occurred. I have written some code that exports the results into a excel file with the correct channel names, but I do not have a time record.
[This is my code for exporting the EEG data to CSV][1]

### Code Exporting EEG Data

```
import numpy as np

import mne
 
edf = mne.io.read_raw_edf(r"Path name from external drive\PN00\PN00-1.edf")

np.savetxt('PN00-1Testv2.csv', edf.get_data().T, delimiter=',')
```

I have created a simple time code, but I do not know how to input that code into my current code. If anyone could help me out that would be great
[This is my Time loop code:][2]

### Time Loop Code

```
import datetime

import numpy as np

import mne

import pandas as pd

import xlwt

import openpyxl as op


Time_start = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,19,39,33,00) 

Time_increment = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=0.00195)


x_TimeEnd = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,20,22,58) 


while Time_start <= x_TimeEnd:

    Time_start += datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=0.00195)

    print(Time_start)
```

The above code loops until Time_start is less than or equal to x_TimeEnd. I am hoping to get something like this into my excel output so that for each record of EEG data I have a corresponding Time output.

The sampling rate of the EEG Data is 512Hz
And the channels in the EDF Files are
Channel 1: Fp1   Channel 2: F3      Channel 3: C3      Channel 4: P3      Channel 5: 1      Channel 6: F7
Channel 7: T3      Channel 8: T5      Channel 9: Fc1      Channel 10: Fc5      Channel 11: Cp1
Channel 12: Cp5      Channel 13: F9      Channel 14: Fz      Channel 15: Cz      Channel 16: Pz
Channel 17: Fp2      Channel 18: F4      Channel 19: C4      Channel 20: P4      Channel 21: O2
Channel 22: F8      Channel 23: T4      Channel 24: T6      Channel 25: Fc2      Channel 26: Fc6
Channel 27: Cp2      Channel 28: Cp6      Channel 29: F10      Channel 33: EKG 1
Channel 34: EKG 2

Please excuse any formatting errors as this is my first time using Stack Overflow. I have included images in the hopes that it would
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O38tF.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnZkg.png

Comment: please provide the code in text format, also use `snake_case` for variables

Comment: I have no idea what snake_case is or how it relates to variables. I am a beginner in python and just want my code to work I do not need anything superficial to be added to it.

Comment: snake_case is when variables are named this way. all lowercase letters and if multiple words this `_`(underscore) is used as space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the edf files already have timestamps which can be read using the mne module. Therefore, I would propose to make use of it instead of generating new timestamps. The mne.io.Raw method [to_data_frame](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.Raw.html#mne.io.Raw.to_data_frame) converts the object to a pandas data frame and allows you to specify the time format.

For example:

```
import mne
edf = mne.io.read_raw_edf(r"Path name from external drive\PN00\PN00-1.edf")
data = edf.to_data_frame(index="time", time_format="datetime")
data.to_csv("PN00-1Testv3.csv")
```

The "time_format" parameter takes *None, "ms", "datetime",* or *"timedelta"* as a value. For more information, I would like to recommend reading the documentation.

Comment: Insulanus you are a life Saver! One thing thought I got a pop up that said excel had problems opening the file? The file opens and their is data but I think it is related to a row limit?

Comment: Although I have never used MS Excel to deal with large datasets, there seems to be an [add-in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed) which allows you to import such datasets. Another option would be to stick with Python or to choose another program for reading. Maybe I should clarify that a comma-separated values (csv) file is not an excel file and that it can be read by many other programs.